# What's the best way to support Facebook login in a secure way and avoiding eavesdropping from a malicious user?

Tags: security, cookies, ssl, https, facebook-javascript-sdk

Facebook has done great work on preventing eavesdropping (with tools like Firesheep) by supporting https on all facebook.com pages, but does not provide similar levels of security for 3rd party sites.

Right now it's possible to eavesdrop the traffic from a 3rd party website which is using the Facebook JS SDK and get a user's signed fbsr_APP_ID cookie which a website should use to authenticate their users.

**Is there a way to set this cookie with the *secure* parameter so that it's only transmitted over HTTPS connections?**

I have read both the documentation and the JavaScript SDK source code and it doesn't seem possible. **So if it's not possible, which other authentication method would you suggest to avoid eavesdropping of this cookie?**

Comment: "and get a user's signed fbsr_APP_ID cookie" --- what can you do having `fbsr_APP_ID` cookie?

Comment: You can then send it to the 3rd party website which it belongs to, they will decode that signed cookie using their Facebook secret key, get a code, exchange it with Facebook to get an access token, and finally sign you in to that 3rd party website :)

Comment: oh, right! For some reason I thought there is something  you (as a person who doesn't have secret key) could do with it.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not fully getting the issue, but the request from Javascript to Facebook is done on HTTPS (right?), and cookies on your own website are only set if you do a `FB.init` with `cookies: true`. So if you have `cookies: false` there, and you set the cookie manually secure (assuming that you want a cookie, and not just client-side storage), nothing can be sniffed (right?)

Comment: @Claude: yes! that's what I was looking for. I'll set cookies:false and then manually pass the access token or signed request through SSL. Please enter this as an answer so I can award you the bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'm too late for the bounty, but I'll happily take the "accepted answer" :)

As noted in the remark, on `FB.init` you specify, whether you want the facebook JS SDK to set cookies for you with the `cookies` option, it even looks like by default no cookies are set: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/

Then afterwards use your own javascript to store the fbsr_APP_ID any way you want (secure cookie, client side storage, etc).